# A sum related to binomial theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> If $\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{1-x} = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$
>
> then $\displaystyle\sum_{\gamma = 1}^{50}a_{\gamma} = ??$

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS1Ea.jpg)

This is a sum related to evaluating a series, from the chapter binomial theorem.

This is how I tried to solve the question

[image: my approach]

I took the $(1-x)$ from the denominator to the numerator making it a $$(1-x)^{-1}$$
and then expanded it binomially, and I tried to find the sum of the coefficients of $$x,x^2,x^3,....,x^{50}$$
However my answer isn't matching. I got $1325$ but the answer is $149$.

update:i do get my mistake, but
how do i go about solving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first few terms are correct.  But you only have three terms in the numerator, so the series is $1+2x+3x^2+3x^4+3x^5+...$

Comment: so how do i approach the problem??

Comment: Your work is correct instead of that.  Instead of 2+3+4+...51, you do 2+3+3+3+...+3.

Answer (score 2):

By considering,

$\begin{array}{rcccccc}
   \frac{1}{1-x}   & =  & 1 & + & x & + & x^{2}+\ldots + x^{50} + \ldots \\
   \frac{x}{1-x}   & =  &   &   & x & + & x^{2}+\ldots + x^{50} + \ldots \\
   \frac{x^2}{1-x} & =  &   &   &   &   & x^{2}+\ldots + x^{50} + \ldots \\
 \end{array}$

Hence the sum is $50+50+49=149$.

Answer (score 1):

The general expansion is $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2...\infty$ so now we need sum of coefficients upto $50$. If we see the pattern we see that $(x^2+x+2)(1)=3$ sum of coeeficients. For $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)$ its 6 so its an AP. So we need sum upto $50$ which is $49\times 3=147$ but 1 term will be $x^{51}$ which we dont need so we get only $+2$ for last term so its $147+2=149$ . Hope its clear.